# Ubuntu server 20.04 setup network problem

Tags: networking, server

Installing ubuntu server 20.04 via live cd. I am at the network setup

Manual setup static ip (I am using public IP Address) and i get the error shown after entering the IP

subnet: 255.255.255.224/27

Address xxx.xxx.219.146

**xxx.xxx.219.146 is not contained in 255.255.255.224/27**

Gateway xxx.xxx.219.132

This of course is incorrect as it is contained in the subnet The IP range is from xxx.xxx.219.128 through to xxx.xxx.219.159

Useable IP's are from  xxx.xxx.219.132 - xxx.xxx.219.158

You cannot proceed with the setup as it does not allow you to with the above error. Unless you select DHCP which i do not use. As it also does not get assigned an IP from DHCP the interface is auto disabled.

Any ideas on where i am incorrect or work around would be greatly appreciated :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: If i enter just the subnet 255.255.255.224 it gives the error ***Should be in CIDR form xx.xx.xx.xx/yy***

Comment: 255.255.255.224 is not a valid *subnet*. It can be, however, a valid *subnet mask*. The two are not interchangeable.

Comment: Thats what happens when you get brain strain I should have noticed it before i posted :)

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out it is asking for a subnet not a subnet mask

instead of the subnet 255.255.255.224/27

i needed to enter the range xxx.xxx.219.128/27
:)